# Site bounces when scrolling. CSS Issue?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been playing with the CSS of my site and have now noticed that when you scroll down or up on this page: http://famigami.com/Testsite/?p=1 the whole page bounces or shakes.

Essentially, the site is made up of four large sections: Header, Image, Content and Footer. All sections are fixed position except for the content, which scrolls.

Can someone help me pin down why the site (all areas with position: fixed) bounces?

The main CSS file can be downloaded here: http://famigami.com/Testsite/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/assets/css/blue.min.css

(The above file doesn't format correctly here and is way too long to manually fix)

The following is my child theme CSS file:

```
.navbar-inner .social-block {
float: right;
}

.navbar-wrapper .navbar h2 {
text-align: right;
float: left;
}

div.brand.span3 {
position: absolute;
}

div.navbar-wrapper.clearfix.span9 {
float: right;
}

.carousel-caption {
background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
max-width: 40%; /* was 60% */
margin-left: 2%; /* was 11% */
padding: 1%;  /* was 5% */
position: absolute;
left: 17%;
bottom:0px; /* hugs the bottom of the slider */
}

/* shrink the Title field */
.carousel-caption h1 {
font-size: 24px; /* was inherited from h1 (38.5px) */
line-height: 1; /*was 1.25 */
}

/* shrink the description field */
.carousel-caption .lead {
font-size: 16px; /* was inherited from lead (21 px) */
line-height: 1; /* was 1.25 */
}

.carousel {
width: 42%;
float: left;
position: fixed;
top: 125px;
}

.carousel .item {
height: 699px;
}

#main-wrapper {
width: 57%;
margin:0;
padding: 5px 0 10px 5px;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
float: right;
top: 125px;
position: relative;
}

.container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-static-top .container, .span12 {
width: auto;
}

#footer {
bottom:0;
width:100%;
float: left;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
}

body {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}

footer#footer .colophon .social-block a {
float: left;
}

.row {
margin-left: auto;
}

.tc-header {
position: fixed;
}

.carousel-caption {
max-width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
padding: 1%;
left: 0;
}

#content.span9 {
width: 695px !important;
}
```

For those with wordpress, you can run Customizr theme at default and paste my child theme's CSS. Just be sure to disable Featured Pages (Customize -> Front Page -> Featured Pages Options) and enable the right sidebar (Customize -> Pages & Posts Layout -> global default layout).

Comment: Looks fine on mine and I was looking in FF and Chrome

Comment: I see the problem on internet explorer when the screen is half size. Ghost in the machine? I'm curious too!

Comment: Yeah, the problem seems to occur most visibly in IE.